# JavaScript / jQuery - calculate number of days, receiving input data and output data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two fields of data entry, date of entry and date of out, which receive data using a datepicker. Is it possible to calculate the number of days, take into account the values of the date of entry and date of out, and save it in the field number of nights? How can I do this?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Date Entry</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                <input name="DateEntry" id="DateEntry"  class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">DateOut</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                <input name="DateOut" id="DateOut" class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">NºNights</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i></span>
                <input name="Nights" class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code with your update of date format being `DD/MM/YYYY`:

**jQuery**

> I highly suggest using Momentjs.  It is user friendly and very powerful when working with dates & times!  That is what my solution will use.  Otherwise you will have to do a bunch of parsing in order to match your date format.  Just make sure that your format doesn't change or else you will have to edit this!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#TestOne').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
  });

  $('#TestTwo').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
  });

   $("#DateOut").blur(function() {
     var str1 = $("#DateEntry").val();
     var str2 = $("#DateOut").val();

     var dateEntry = moment(str1, "DD/MM/YYYY");
     var dateOut = moment(str2, "DD/MM/YYYY");
     var range = dateOut.diff(dateEntry, 'days');

   $("#NightsBetween").val(range);
  });
});
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE**

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8jpmkcr5/1302/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tested it but in mine it does not automatically appear the number of nights ... my datepicker is in the format DD / MM / YYYY HH: mm: ss ... could it be because of this?

Comment: Absolutely it is because of that.  You are probably receiving a `NaN` result.  See my update.

Comment: I've updated my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4noonk9/4/) again to exactly what you told me that format is.  Still working for me.

Comment: this is giving the value I gave in value in html ... but if I click on the box and open the datetimepickers 2 it does not calculate the days

Comment: Can you post your jQuery?

Comment: Updated my fiddle to exactly what you have using datetimepicker. I've added two id's.. TestOne and TestTwo to get the input addon's working

Comment: You can't achieve the Number of Nights value on page load.. because the Date Entry and Date Out are blank..

Comment: I already received the value even though everything is empty with your new solution! I am not is receiving the correct value! I am putting between the days 17 and 24 and the end result is giving me 2 and it should be 7

Answer (score 1):

```
var start = $('#DateEntry').val();
var end = $('#DateOut').val();

// end - start returns difference in milliseconds 
var diff = new Date(end - start);

// get nights
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

//set nights
$('#Nights').val(days)
```

This is client side code. You have to call this from document.load or may be onchange event of both entry and out dates.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I put this inside a <script> and when entering the dates ... it does not automatically fill me the number of nights ... you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar approach with the hook to handle the text changing.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Date Diff in Nights</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">entry</i></span>
        <input name="DateEntry" id="DateEntry" class="form-control" type="text" >

        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">out</i></span>
        <input name="DateOut" id="DateOut" class="form-control" type="text" >

        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-list-ol">nights</i></span>
        <input name="Nights" id="Nights" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var input = document.getElementById('DateEntry');
        input.addEventListener('input', calcNights);
        var input2 = document.getElementById('DateOut');
        input2.addEventListener('input', calcNights);
        function calcNights() {

            try {
                var nightsout = document.getElementById('Nights');
                var element = document.getElementById('DateEntry');
                var entryDate = new Date(element.value);
                var out = document.getElementById('DateOut');
                var outDate = new Date(out.value);
                // Set to noon to avoid any DST errors
                outDate.setHours(12, 0, 0);
                entryDate.setHours(12, 0, 0);
                var difference = outDate - entryDate;
                var nights = Math.round(difference / 8.64e7);
                if (isNaN(nights) || nights < 0) {
                    nightsout.value = '';
                    return;
                }
                nightsout.value = nights;
            }
            catch (ex) {
                //ignore
            }
        } 
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but did not work, maybe due to date format that is 'DD / MM / YYYY HH: mm: ss'

Comment: I get this datetimepicker format DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss

Comment: I just saw you had text inputs. What's the error with that format? is the difference NaN all the time?